# Different kinds of buttons on CToolBar

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

Give me a tip please how to add different kinds of buttons (I need to have pushbuttons and radio buttons) on the same CToolBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CMFCToolbar::ReplaceButton.

You replace the regular button with either one of the default CMFCToolBarButton derived classed or with one of your own derived class.

The toolbar need to have a "placeholder" button (empty button) at the position you want to replace the button.

for example to replace a toolbar button with a combo box:

```
CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton myCombo(IDC_BUTTON_TO_REPLACE, GetCmdMgr()->GetCmdImage(IDC_BUTTON_TO_REPLACE, FALSE), CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, 80);
myCombo.m_strText.LoadString(IDS_MY_STRING);
myToolbar.ReplaceButton(IDC_BUTTON_TO_REPLACE, myCombo);
```

There are a couple of standard "buttons" available (in particular):
CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton to replace a toolbar button with an edit box.
CMFCToolBarDateTimeCtrlImpl to replace a toolbar button with a date picker
CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton to replace a toolbar button with a combo box.

(there are a couple more for menus and one for "outlook" ).

Good luck.

Comment: But is it possible to do it using CToolbar, instead of CMFCToolbar?

Comment: I think you can use CToolBar::SetButtonStyle (it's been a while, and I remember that it was hard)for that, but if I were you, i'd start using CMFCToolbar.